# populate jqGrid from array of data

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have jqGrid like this

```
jQuery("#list2").jqGrid({
    datatype: "local",
    colNames: ['Name', 'Email', 'Mobile', 'Address', 'Institution', 'Studying Year', 'Registered Date', 'No Of Courses', 'Book Codes'],
    colModel: [
        {name: 'name',index: 'name',align: "center"},
        {name: 'user_email',index: 'user_email',align: "center"},
        {name: 'mobile',index: 'mobile',align: "center"},
        {name: 'address',index: 'address',align: "center"},
        {name: 'institution',index: 'institution',align: "center"},
        {name: 'studyingyear',index: 'studyingyear',align: "center"},
        {name: 'created',index: 'created',align: "center"},
        {name: 'noofcourses',index: 'noofcourses',align: "center"},
        {name: 'book_code',index: 'book_code',align: "center"}
    ],
   gridview: true
});

$.ajax({
    url:'http://localhost:8090/cbsapp/adminlogin/serverforusers.php?limit=20&offset=0',
    dataType: 'json'
}).done(function(data) {

    var jqData = data.rows
    console.log(jqData);
    for(var i=0;i<=jqData.length;i++)
       jQuery("#list2").jqGrid('addRowData',i+1,jqData[i]);
}).fail(function(error){
    console.log(error)   
})
```

The data I am getting in is in array

```
[{
    "id": "1",
    "cell": [" Kousic Prabu Mohanasundaravad", "magickousi@gmail.com", "9159360960", "263A,Thattankulam rd, Puthunagar, Palani", "YSMU", "Others", "2017-12-08 09:33:31", "1", ["FMGE DS"]]
}, {
    "id": "2",
    "cell": [" Navdeep", "navdeepgohel@gmail.com", "9207367900", "Kevadiya colony ", "DIAMS ", "Final year", "2017-11-20 23:08:13", "0", [null]]
}, {
    "id": "3",
    "cell": [" Nikish nehra", "nikishnehra01@gmail.com", "8168965998", "Hissar cantt hissar ", "Kharkiv national medical university ", "Final year", "2017-12-11 04:35:34", "1", ["FMGE DS"]]
}, {
    "id": "4",
    "cell": [" Vynatheya Chowdary", "vyna984@gmail.com", "7032207755", "d.no:3270 putlur road tadipatri Anantapur ", "Government Medical College, Anantapur", "3 Year", "2017-08-29 01:47:16", "1", ["SOCH UB"]]
}]
```

I am using cell key as an array to populate the data:

```
for(var i=0;i<=jqData.length;i++)
    jQuery("#list2").jqGrid('addRowData',i+1,jqData[i]);
```

But the data is not whowing in the grid but table/grid is created properly with all blank rows.
Please help.

Comment: Which version of jqGrid is used? Does your grid have existing data and you need to add additional data or this data can overwrite existing grid data if any. just to note that addRowData can not be used in a format of data you use.

Answer (score 0):

You should add

```
localReader: { repeatitems: true }
```

option to jqGrid because of the JSON format, which you use. Additionally, it's very bad to use `addRowData` in the loop to fill the data in the grid. It's much more effective to use `data` parameter of jqGrid instead. See https://jsfiddle.net/s5m43jme/ as an example. A